# Magit does not consider ~/.gitignore

Tags: git, emacs, magit

Using `magit` (version: `20190413.1201`) with Emacs 26.1, and I notice that `magit` ignores what my global .gitignore file (`~/.gitignore`) says. For instance, tilde files (`somefile~`) continue to show up in magit, but not when using normal command line git (from a proper terminal). Any ideas?

There is a similar question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14122/both-vc-and-magit-cannot-see-global-gitignore, with the response being:

> It turned out Emacs's HOME and Git's were different. I've added the HOME environment variable and moved my .emacs there. All works fine now. Thanks @YoungFrog, you made me think about my HOME

But I don't really understand that sentence. $HOME is the same when querying Emacs or the terminal process.

Comment: Git doesn't have a global ignore file by default. Did you add one by modifying your `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: Yes, that's why it works outside of magit (`excludesfile = /Users/myname/.gitignore`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, tilde files (somefile~) continue to show up in magit,

Make sure those files are not *already* versioned (tracked by Git), because no amount of `.gitignore` (global or not) would remove them from Git/Magit consideration.
You would need to remove them (`git rm --cached`) first, before seeing those files *not* showing up anymore.

Comment: Not exactly what I did but your answer is correct in spirit. I removed the last ~ file from my repository before staging (but forgot how, I think through magit itself), and new ones do not show up anymore. Therefore I select this as the correct answer.